# how to get the list of objects from the JSON String which has the multiple reference units using the mapper?

Tags: java, json

My requirement is to get all selected columns and saving into database as Json String , and again a i have to convert those back to List of Objects and return to the UI,
My Json look like this, i want the List of dimensions, how i can do this? please suggest me.

```
{
    "dimensions": [{
        "displayName": "Advertised Products",
        "name": "Product",
        "selectable": false,
        "multipleSelect": true,
        "hasFavorites": true,
        "showCancel": false,
        "showClear": false,
        "hasCustomObjects": true,
        "isPrimary": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "editable": true
    }, {
        "displayName": "Companion Products",
        "name": "Product",
        "selectable": false,
        "multipleSelect": true,
        "hasFavorites": true,
        "showCancel": false,
        "showClear": false,
        "hasCustomObjects": true,
        "isPrimary": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "editable": true
    }, {
        "displayName": "Fsp Products",
        "name": "Product",
        "selectable": false,
        "multipleSelect": true,
        "hasFavorites": true,
        "showCancel": false,
        "showClear": false,
        "hasCustomObjects": true,
        "isPrimary": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "editable": true
    }]
}
```

Comment: don't you know how to save data to a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a DimensionTO pojo which has Dimension object reference, setters and getters.

```
    public class DimensionTO {
    private Dimension dimension;

    public Dimension getDimension () {
        return dimension;
    }

    public void setUser(Dimension dimension) {
        this.dimension= dimension;
    }

}
```

Use the object mapper to read the list of dimensions,

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
WatcherTO[] dimensionList = mapper.readValue(passYourJson, WatcherTO[].class);
```

Now we can iterate the dimensionList to get the each dimension object.